# Passing a string's variable by reference in Android

Tags: android, string, pointers, reference, sudoku

**Hello** all I'm new to android programming and I have a problem.
I created a sudoku app with preset puzzles for 3 difficulties using an e - book's directions.
The thing is that I made a puzzle generator for my puzzles to make them infinite.Now here is my problem :
To save your pre-defined puzzle in the book's example you had to use :

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREF_PUZZLE,
toPuzzleString(puzzle)).commit();
```

toPuzzleString obviously converts the puzzle into a string(which was stored before in a 1 dimention array)

In order to load your saved settings to make the Continue option to work you had to use :

```
puz = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREF_PUZZLE,easyPuzzle);
```

BUT this works for a predefined puzzle stored in a private final string called "easypuzzle" at the beggining of the game.class . My puzzle is generated and stored in a 1 dimentional array when user clicks New Game.As a result I have to pass my generated puzzle as a reference(this is what I think) cause i tried to pass it like this :

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREF_PUZZLE,toPuzzleString(puzzle));
```

and when I close the game or just go back and try to Continue my game generates a new puzzle for me (or this is what I think it is) instead of loading the saved one.

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me , or tell me how to pass my puzzle as a reference like in c++?
Thank you all for your time any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Where are you putting the saving and loading of your preferences? Not sure if I'm understanding what you're getting at, because the getString you have above with easyPuzzle, is simply using easyPuzzle as the default to load if it can't find something already saved. As in, it should work for your case too, but doesn't sound like it's being saved at the correct time, or loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, your puzzle may not be saved in preferences correctly.  In order to check, change the getString(...) method to something like this:

```
String puzzleFromPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREF_PUZZLE, null);

if( null == puzzleFromPrefs ) {
  // Then you know that it wasn't saved correctly...
}
```

This will cause null to be returned if the puzzle hasn't already been saved in the preferences.  This will help narrow down where the issue may be.

Comment: Heya guys thanks for your answers.
Hey dule I put the save code in the 

protected void onPause() of my game.class which handles all my game creation etc.
I think that nothing is saved you are right but I don't know why.

@px3j I'm trying to do the thing you mentioned mate and put this code in my load function and afterwards I use an if statement like you mentioned and inside if statement I use Log.d(TAG,"Game not saved") but I don't get this error message in LogCat...

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To be more specific in the OnCreate method I use these commands :

`int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_EASY);`

Then 
`puzzle = getPuzzle(diff);`
Then My puzzle's view commands
And to be able to continue if activity is restarted :

`getIntent().putExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_CONTINUE);`

The rest of my code which actually saves the puzzle goes in my OnPause method like this :

`getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(PREF_PUZZLE, toPuzzleString(puzzle)).commit();`

I'm stuck here and desperate to find out what's wrong..Thanks in advance